# array_multisort for number and string

Tags: php

In PHP, do numbers have lower ASCII values compare to characters? I understand how array_multisort works, but when it comes to numbers and characters, which will come first if we sort ascending order.

This is the example from PHP array_multisort.

```
$ar = array(
       array("10", 11, 100, 100, "a"),  //10
       array(   1,  2, "2",   3,   1)
      );
array_multisort($ar[0], SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING,
                $ar[1], SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC);
var_dump($ar);


array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [1]=>
    int(100)
    [2]=>
    int(100)
    [3]=>
    int(11)
    [4]=>
    string(1) "a"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(3)
    [2]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [3]=>
    int(2)
    [4]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Looking at the example above, we start with "10" as the first value in the search. Why doesn't the search sort 11 as the next value, but it put the 100 which is the next value as we are sorting in ascending order?

The array_multisort then jumps to the second array, as it has two 100s in the first search.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `SORT_NATURAL` to sort them in the order your expecting. (Same as [`natsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php))

```
$ar = array(
    array("10", 11, 100, 100, "a"),  //10
    array(   1,  2, "2",   3,   1)
);
array_multisort($ar[0], SORT_ASC, SORT_NATURAL,
    $ar[1], SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC );  
var_dump($ar);
```

Outputs...

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(5) {
    [0] =>
    string(2) "10"
    [1] =>
    int(11)
    [2] =>
    int(100)
    [3] =>
    int(100)
    [4] =>
    string(1) "a"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(5) {
    [0] =>
    int(1)
    [1] =>
    int(2)
    [2] =>
    int(3)
    [3] =>
    string(1) "2"
    [4] =>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nigel.. array_multisort is confusing. Your remark has shed some light into the problem.